# Mistakes in llvm instruction::getOpcode() and getOpcodeName

Tags: llvm

I find there may be some errors in my llvm pass project. I wrote a little program to try to print out all the instructions and their corresponding opcode. I use Instruction::getOpcode() and Instruction::getOpcodeName().

## But the result looks a little bit odd. Following is my result:

```
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
load
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
load
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
load
  store i32 0, i32* %1
getelementptr
  %2 = call i64 @time(i64* null) #3
select
  %3 = trunc i64 %2 to i32
zext
  call void @srand(i32 %3) #3
select
  %4 = call i32 @rand() #3
select
  %5 = srem i32 %4, 10
frem
  store i32 %5, i32* %a, align 4
getelementptr
  %6 = call i32 @rand() #3
select
  %7 = srem i32 %6, 10
frem
  store i32 %7, i32* %b, align 4
getelementptr
  %8 = load i32* %a, align 4
store
  %9 = load i32* %b, align 4
store
  %10 = icmp sgt i32 %8, %9
fcmp
  br i1 %10, label %11, label %14
switch
  %12 = load i32* %a, align 4
store
  %13 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %12)
select
  br label %17
switch
  %15 = load i32* %b, align 4
store
  %16 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %15)
select
  br label %17
switch
  %18 = load i32* %1
store
  ret i32 %18
br
```

I try to print out every instruction opcodeName after instruction, but every instruction get a wrong opcodeName. I have also checked the opcode for each opcodeName, and they are also wrong. I do not know exactly where to find the enum of instruction list, but I think I have ever found it before, and wrong opcodeName is correlating to opcode. Looks like they both shift from right case by 2 unit.

Have you ever faced the problem like this?

I also attach the code of my llvm pass as follows:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvmFaultInjector.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  // Hello - The first implementation, without getAnalysisUsage.
  struct Hello : public ModulePass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    Hello() : ModulePass(ID) {}

    bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {
        Module::iterator fi, fie;
        Function::iterator bi, bie;
        BasicBlock::iterator ii, iie;

        /* test a example : delete first instruction of test file */
        Instruction * inst;

        for(fi = M.begin(), fie = M.end(); fi != fie; fi++)
        {
            for(bi = fi->begin(), bie = fi->end(); bi != bie; bi++)
            {
                for(ii = bi->begin(), iie = bi->end(); ii != iie; ii++)
                {
                    inst = (Instruction *)(ii);
                    errs() << *inst << '\n';
                    errs() << inst->getOpcodeName() << '\n';
                }
            }
        }

        /* delete instruction*/
        /*llvmFaultInjector::tranBranchDelete(inst);
        */      
        return true;
    }
  };
}

char Hello::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("CFCFaultInject", "llvm CFCFaultInjector");
```

Comment: That is awfully strange. What version of llvm are you using, and how you did you build it?

Comment: In fact I am not sure about my version number. All I did is just following tutorial in http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html. I think I have did every step on that. Quite strange.